# GridDB (TXN_WAIT_FOR_TRANSACTION_END) - Transaction Event Processing in Standby Status

Tags: python, griddb

I'm encountering an issue with GridDB and would appreciate your assistance in resolving it.

Error Details:

```
Error Code: 10905
Error Message: TXN_WAIT_FOR_TRANSACTION_END
Error Type: ERROR
Description: Processing of transaction event continued to be in standby status.
Circumstances:
This error arises when processing transaction events in my GridDB setup, where transactions appear to be stuck in standby status.
```

I attempted to address the issue by reviewing the transaction logs and checking for any long-running transactions. I also optimized my code to ensure that transactions are committed or rolled back promptly. Additionally, I adjusted the transaction timeout settings to see if that would help resolve the problem.

but the problem still exists can you help me guys?